# calling a java servlet from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-applications, servlets

I am trying to create a web application using the MVC design pattern. For the GUI part I would like to use JavaScript. And for the controller Java Servlets.

Now I have never really worked with JavaScript, so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to call a Java Servlet from JavaScript and how to get the response from the Servlet.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

So you want to fire [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) calls to the servlet? For that you need the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object in JavaScript. Here's a Firefox compatible example:

```
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            alert(data);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet', true);
    xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

This is however very verbose and not really crossbrowser compatible. For the best crossbrowser compatible way of firing ajaxical requests and traversing the HTML DOM tree, I recommend to grab [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Here's a rewrite of the above in jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

Either way, the Servlet on the server should be mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/myservlet` (you can change this to your taste) and have at least [`doGet()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) implemented and write the data to the response as follows:

```
String data = "Hello World!";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(data);
```

This should show `Hello World!` in the JavaScript alert.

You can of course also use [`doPost()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-), but then you should use `'POST'` in `xhr.open()` or use `$.post()` instead of `$.get()` in jQuery.

Then, to show the data in the HTML page, you need to manipulate the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). For example, you have a

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

in the HTML where you'd like to display the response data, then you can do so instead of `alert(data)` of the 1st example:

```
document.getElementById("data").firstChild.nodeValue = data;
```

In the jQuery example you could do this in a more concise and nice way:

```
$('#data').text(data);
```

To go some steps further, you'd like to have an easy accessible data format to transfer more complex data. Common formats are XML and JSON. For more elaborate examples on them, head to [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Comment: I did what you said. But the servlet returns html code which is inside it as response. the alert(data) shows html code in browser's alert

Answer (score 6):

The code here will use AJAX to print text to an HTML5 document dynamically
(Ajax code is similar to book Internet & WWW (Deitel)):

## Javascript code:

```
var asyncRequest;    
function start(){
    try
    {
        asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", stateChange, false);
        asyncRequest.open('GET', '/Test', true);    //   /Test is url to Servlet!
        asyncRequest.send(null);
    }
    catch(exception)
   {
    alert("Request failed");
   }
}

function stateChange(){
if(asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200)
    {
    var text = document.getElementById("text");         //  text is an id of a 
    text.innerHTML = asyncRequest.responseText;         //  div in HTML document
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", start(), false);
```

## Servlet java code:

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet{
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException{
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Servlet wrote this! (Test.java)");
    }
}
```

## HTML document

```
 <div id = "text"></div>
```

## EDIT

I wrote answer above when I was new with web programming. I let it stand, but the javascript part should definitely be in jQuery instead, it is 10 times easier than raw javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) for the javascript calls and some implementation of JSR311 like [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) for the service layer, which would delegate to your controllers.

This will help you with all the underlying logic of handling the HTTP calls and your data serialization, which is a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I read jsp not javascript.  You need to do something like (note that this is a relative url and may be different depending on the url of the document this javascript is in):

```
document.location = 'path/to/servlet';
```

Where your servlet-mapping in web.xml looks something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/to/servlet*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Not it is from JavaScript, but that level of trivial stuff is far closer to being the controller than a view.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function callServlet()


{
 document.getElementById("adminForm").action="./Administrator";
 document.getElementById("adminForm").method = "GET";
 document.getElementById("adminForm").submit();
```

}

```
<button type="submit"  onclick="callServlet()" align="center"> Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById("<<button-id>>");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.href= "<<full-servlet-path>>" (eg. http://localhost:8086/xyz/servlet)
});
```