# how to call a servlet using ajax (post) to send parameters...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

i need to call a servlet from javascript by using ajax post method and also need to send some parameters to that servlet. How can i do that. I have spent too much time to get rid of this but still no luck...! All help appreciated.....Please help

Comment: Any code you already tried? [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is it already quite good explained...

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028490/calling-a-java-servlet-from-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using jQuery is very easy...

```
$.post("yourServletUrl",{"param1":"1","param2":"2"},function(data){},"json");
```

this is method post  
first      `param: servlet url`
second param: `params`
third     `param: callback`
the last param: `response data` format  ("json","xml"...)

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:URL,
    data:{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
    type:'POST',
    dataType : 'xml',   /* use 'jsonp' for cross domain*/
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // access response data
    },
    error:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log('Service call failed!');
    }
});
```

Comment: <servlet>
  <description>Serves files uploaded via the File Upload demo</description>
   <display-name>File Servlet</display-name>
   <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.analytica.net.upload.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>                                                                 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/FileUploadServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                       $.ajax({

                        type : 'GET',

                          url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Servletname',

                          data : $('#formname').serialize(),

                           success : function(response) {

                            alert(response)

                        }

                    });
```