# Passing a value from servlet doGet() to javascript's $.get() returning whole HTML instead

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

My work necessitates working with Java logic and Javascript. So, now I am trying to pass a value to javascript once a doGet() of a servlet is executed. Somehow, instead of some Java string, javascript displays the whole HTML String as the value (`"<html>...<body>....</body>...</html>"`).

The following is an excerpt from the **hello.jsp**:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get('hello', function(data) {
        $('#data').text(data);
    });
</script>

<body>
<div id="input">
    <form action="hello" method="get">
    <p><input type="text" name="query" value="${messages.query}"><input type="submit" value="Go!"></p>
    <hr>
    </form>

</div>

<div id="data"></div>
</body>
```

Except from **HelloController.java**:

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String data = "Hello World from doGet()!";
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(data);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
/* 
...
*/
    }

}
```

So, once doGet() is executed, I want `"Hello World from doGet()"` to be passed back as `data` to javascript's `$.get()`, but instead `"<html>...<body>....</body>...</html>"` is displayed in the `data` div. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what your `doGet` is doing.

```
String data = "Hello World from doGet()!"; // creates a String
response.setContentType("text/plain"); // sets the content type
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // sets the encoding
response.getWriter().write(data); // writes the value of the String to the response
```

and finally

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

What does this do? The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) states

> Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP
>   file, or HTML file) on the server. This method allows one servlet to
>   do preliminary processing of a request and another resource to
>   generate the response.

A JSP is a `Servlet`. So when you forward to that JSP, it is rendered and the generated HTML gets written to the HTTP response. If you don't want that, get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to replicate the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028490/calling-a-java-servlet-from-javascript

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that is not the behavior I am looking for. I guess I am looking for the doGet() method to update my div only. Is this possible?

Comment: @ijk doGet is a method of a Servlet. It is completely unrelated to a div rendered by a browser. You use ajax as an http client to send requests. Your server uses this servlet and its doGet method to handle the request and produce a response. If you want that response to only contain a plain/text string value, then that's all you should make it contain.

Comment: Actually I fixed what I was trying to do. Thanks!