# how do i setAttribute to request obj - in javaScript file of jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

i made a servlet using java-ee (know as: j2ee)
the mvc is a controller (java), and views (html-js-css) pages

i hava a controller that mapping the url
like `...../controller/index.jsp`

so if we navigate this, index.jsp will opened and all the js & css it need.

when user click on a button in the page, it will open an Ajax connection to the controller.
like i saw here:
[calling a java servlet from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028490/calling-a-java-servlet-from-javascript)

> $.get('../controller/url_to_mapped?firstStringParameter=aaa,
>   function(responseData) {
>
> });

for example: in the link i wrote below i send a string parameter called `firstStringParameter` and it's value is `aaa`.
**how do i send a variable and not just a string parameters from js file??**

if it's only in html code so we was write <% request.setAttribute("key", value)%>
**but**, in js i cant write java code.

**edited:**
**Add some code:**
servlet.java:

```
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

test.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255" pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% String param = "foo";%>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var param_js_context = '<%=param%>';
alert(param_js_context);
```

and the alert result was: `<%=param%>` as is.

Answer (score 2):

As i got from your question following will be the solution

You have to create a variable in java script code only when you are writing you code in jsp file .

snippet are below

var foo = '<%=param%>';

and you can pass that parameter in ajax call as a javascript variable

Comment: hi, i try exactly what the other guy write, i think this is what you meant, but its does not success. what controller get is only value `<%= id%>` as is.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.ajax to post your variables like below:

```js
String id = "123abc"; // your java string in jsp
   ...........

var id = "<%= id%>";   // java String is assigned to a javascript variable....

//Array ofyour javascript variables to be sent to the server:
var formData = {id:id, name:"ravi",age:"31"}; 
 
$.ajax({
    url : "AJAX_POST_URL",  //your servlet or jsp name/path
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
      console.log("response..:"+ data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
       console.log("error...");
    }
});
```

try this and let us know. hope this will help your question.

Comment: i have try what you wrote, but what controller get is only `<%= id%>` and not the real value that i decleared in jsp: `<% String id="123abc"; %>`

Comment: should be something wrong in your code.. please post your proper code to make us clear where you've gone wrong !!

Comment: i added the code, i will appreciate if you will find something to fix it.