# How to call servlet doPost method from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, servlets

I am trying to call a serlvet from javascript. Code below:

```
document.location.href="service1servlet";
```

It perfectly delegates call to the servlet but with an error as:

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

I guess its looking for doGet method in servlet. How do I make it call doPost method in that servlet? Servlet doPost method below:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("THIS IS IN SERVICE!SERVLET AND CAN CHANGE DATABASE");   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using document.location.href it's not possible to send a POST request.

[similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why your servlet should support only POST method? If there's none, I suggest you stick with GET method.

Anyway, you can always call doPost in your doGet method.

Define a doGet method such as the ff. example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

Or if you really need to support only POST method, then the Javascript function you mentioned won't work. POST requests can be done through form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Ajax or by using jQuery.This is the jQuery code to call servlet mapped with url pattern of `/yourServlet`.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.post('yourServlet', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

I would recommend you to go through this

- [calling a java servlet from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028490/calling-a-java-servlet-from-javascript)