# How to pass geolocation values to variable and to sql query in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, geolocation

Following code, I am using to get GeoLocation in jsp/javascript/html.

```
<script>
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        alert(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);
        });

    }

</script>
```

Now, I need to store this values in database, which query is in jsp tag.
How can we store this latitude, longitude values with a variable and then pass to query.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028490/calling-a-java-servlet-from-javascript after this servlet call method to store in db

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**:-

If you are going to submit any form in the jsp the put a hidden value like below

```
<input type="hidden" id="geoLocation" >
```

Then set this when page starts loading i.e. in `windows.onLoad` or after loading the hole page i.e. in jQuery `$document.ready{}`

Set value as

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      document.getElementById("geoLocation").value=position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude;
        }
      );
}
```

And then submit it with the form...

**Option 2** :-

Try to use [AJAX DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/) component which will let you add data to the data base with a single DAO class i.e. simple POJO class

All steps to do it are listed on its official website :- http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html

You will need to include 2 javascript file to your jsp and give DWR access to your DAO methods if you are using MVC but in this case i prefer to make seprate DAO just for DWR and you are Done...