# DynamoDB query from servlet Java Web Application

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to access `DynamoDB` from my java Web Application using a `Servlet`, I am unable to connect to dynamodb through this approach. My code works fine if I place it on another `.java` class and run it as Java Application, in this way I get data from dynamodb and can interact .

Hence my question is: How to connect to it from the web application?

Comment: Can you tell us more - the code you have working from an application should be able to be, for example, in the doGet() method of a servlet.  You would get the data from DynamoDB this way or, for saving, perhaps in the doPost() method.  Let us know a bit more about what issues you're running into.

Comment: Hey ! I fixed my issue, the problem was that the libraries my application needed, had to be inserted not in WEB-INF/lib but at Tomcat home in TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder !!

Answer (score 0):

in the inside web you need  add JAvascript and call to Server,,,
You can try investigate  a like

ApiRest,
AJAX

this a example ,,The anwerd
[calling a java servlet from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028490/calling-a-java-servlet-from-javascript)

Comment: Hi @Irving Navarro Flores thanks for answering , the thing is I need to get data from dynamo so that I can put them in csv and user can download it , which cannot be done on client-side. Therefor I am using a servlet to a file the data from dynamo, and user can download it . Still Tomcat wont start , when I place code for authentication in servlet!